# Can I use cabal to handle non-Haskell libraries?

Tags: haskell, cabal, package-managers, cabal-install

There have been attempt in other package managers to build brigdes to other ecosystems. E.g., there is [composer-npm-bridge](https://github.com/eloquent/composer-npm-bridge), which allows to pull packages from node registry into a PHP project.  Is it possible to build something like this using cabal?  More concretely, how would one go about pulling packages from [luarocks](https://luarocks.org) into a Haskell project?

Comment: I'd have to back up a step and ask how one could even _use_ a lua package in a Haskell package.  Can you clarify your view on that?

Comment: We have [hslua](https://github.com/hslua/hslua), which serves as a bridge between haskell and lua. If the lua package consists of a few lua files only, then one could compile the lua code into the binary (as we do in pandoc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in principle possible: with `build-type: custom`, cabal will compile and run your `Setup.hs` in place of its own build mechanisms, and you can put arbitrary Haskell code in `Setup.hs`. Alternately, if you can fit your setup process into the usual configure-make-make install dance, then the `build-type: configure` option may be just the ticket.

See [the user's guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-build-type) for more complete details on these configuration options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping for some more guidance: are there any examples/code snippets which could serve as a basis for such an undertaking?